# List sorting and getting elements

Tags: kotlin

I have class:

```
class SportMan(
   val name: String,
   val points: Double,
}
```

and list named `SportGuysList` of `Sportman` Objects. I want to create new list from `SportGuysList` that has top 5 `Sportman` objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first sort the list by points descending, take the first 5 players from it, then sort them back by the index in the original list:

```
val topByPoints = SportGuysList.sortedByDescending { it.points }.take(5)
val result = topByPoints.sortedBy { SportGuysList.indexOf(it) }
```

If the `SportGuysList` is big, then searching for an index of each resulting element during sorting may take a long time, so you can remember the original index of each sportsman beside it:

```
val result = 
    SportGuysList.withIndex() // now we have pairs of value-index
    .sortedByDescending { it.value.points }  // sort by points
    .take(5)  // top 5
    .sortedBy { it.index } // sort back by index
    .map { it.value } // take only value from an each indexed pair
```

Try in Kotlin playground: https://pl.kotl.in/kMkpkIdEH

Comment: But this is not working. It returns only sorted by points...  I want to keep same order but take sportguys with top 5 points

Comment: yep @llya it looks good idea but I just tried to debugg it and it returns only sorted by points descending :/

Comment: yes I did! hmmm that looks weird. I will check it out again

Comment: Nope it aint wokring...code is simple i just copy pastead it....  I am using MutableList instead of List -> var sportsmen: MutableList<Maratonac> = mutableListOf(). but is shouldt change anything...

Comment: I've added a link to Kotlin playground with the answer's code. Does it work as you expected there?

Comment: I found where I made a mistake. It was weird order in my list my bad. Thanks, you solved this problem best way